# gridview clickevent android

Tags: android, android-gridview

Iam newbie to android. I had created an application which contains a grid with single column and multiple rows. I had implemented onItemClick method. I need to identify which row has been selected. I cant achieve it through getId() as it returns only same id for all rows. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you populate your grid?  Post your code, including your adapter.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of a grid with a single column?  Why not just use ListView?

Comment: I guess it adapts the number of columns to available screen width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an argument in the `OnItemClickListener` which correspond to the item position.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
    {
        //Selected item is at index "position".
    }
});
```

If you want the exact row of the selection, you can use your columns number, with something like

```
int row = position / columnsNumber
```

Comment: ya its working. but for dynamic grid how can i achieve this??

Comment: What do you call dynamic grid? Even if you want to change the number of columns, I guess you still have a reference to this number somewhere.